# Allow 2 char only on ACF (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My question is the same as the title.
I need to make a text field, with a max allowed character, the problem is that this field will be a ISBN book, so i need to allow numbers and the ‘-‘ char only.

I thinked about using a regex in my php template, but doing this every other character will be saved on my database.
Is there any better solution to this?

Thank you in advance.
Gianmaria Generoso.

Comment: Character Limit can be set on the field in the UI - but I don't really follow - do you want to make sure, that other letters etc. is not being put in - 
I guess the easiest would be to make a field instruction for the user - telling them to only put numbers and dashes in?

Comment: you want to put something like this in `978-3-16-148410-0` so why do you need to remove letters? there will never be a letter in a ISBN right? so just set the char limit to 17? and add a placeholder text with an example?

Comment: Because it happens that users are not "properly intelligent" and we don't want that people can put wrong data on products, visible on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you could do this but there is a very long winded way around this which isn't required.

You can simply add a placeholder to the field for an example, and then where you echo your code use the following:

```
$isbn = get_field('isbn_number');

if(preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $isbn)) : ?>
    <p>You have entered an invalid ISBN number.</p>
<?php else :?>
    <p>ISBN: <?php the_field('isbn_number');
endif; ?>
```

This means that if someone does enter a letter of the alphabet, instead of displaying the incorrect ISBN number, it will, in fact, display the message notfiying them that they have submitted an incorrect number.

Example 1:

```
when $isbn = A-123-BCD-123-EFG
Front end: You have entered an invalid ISBN number.
```

Example 2:

```
when $isbn = 978-3-16-148410-0
Front End: ISBN: 978-3-16-148410-0
```